# JSOUP removing words which occur more than once from attributes

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

Assuming content to be the following:

```html
<p><img src=\"https://abcd.com/pic.jpg\" alt=\"man with a umbrella on terrace with lots of xyz\" width=\"500\" height=\"400\" /></p>
```

If the following lines of code are used, JSOUP removes words that occur more than once in any attribute.

```
Parser parser = Parser.htmlParser(); 
parser.settings(new ParseSettings(true, true));
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(modifiedContent,"",parser);
```

```html
<p><img src=\"https://abcd.com/pic.jpg\" alt=\"man with a umbrella on terrace lots of xyz\" width=\"500\" height=\"400\" /></p>
```

the word **with** is removed. Any suggestions on how to deal with this issue

Comment: Is the original content HTML? Or a `String`?

Comment: That is, are you reading from an HTML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input HTML has the initial quotation mark escaped. This means that, instead of your alt being `man with a umbrella on terrace with lots of xyz`, the value of your alt tag is `"man`. Following the alt tag you essentially have multiple boolean attributes, being `with`, `a`, etc.

JSoup is then stripping out the duplicated boolean attributes, as they have no effect. You should change your HTML to the correct format, without the escaped quotation marks

```
<p><img src="https://abcd.com/pic.jpg" alt="man with a umbrella on terrace with  lots of xyz" width="500" height="400" /></p>
```

Running this locally and System.out-ing the doc produces the correct value of

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p><img src="https://abcd.com/pic.jpg" alt="man with a umbrella on terrace with lots of xyz" width="500" height="400"></p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. HTML editor also validated your point. I used StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava to get rid of the /".